# Write separate lines python serial

Tags: python, pyserial

I try to write few serial commands , each one of the commands should be send separately
I tried to add \n at the end of the line but according to the serial monitor on the computer the lines are not separate

Example of what happens:

Sending:

```
ser.write(bytes.fromhex("01 02 03 04 \n”))
```

And sending next command:

```
 ser.write(bytes.fromhex("05 06 07\n))
```

Received

```
 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
```

Instead:

```
 01 02 03 04

 05 06 07
```

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Obviously `fromhex` doesn't digest something not in hex

Comment: Thank you, so how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Or how can I send a command of end of line?

Answer (score 0):

[`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex) will effectively ignore the newline.

> The string s may have leading and trailing whitespace.

Append `"\n"` to the string produced by `fromhex()`:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("05 06 07\n")
b'\x05\x06\x07'

>>> bytes.fromhex("05 06 07") + b"\n"
b'\x05\x06\x07\n'
```